# Android html load on webview cant work

Tags: android

when i use webview to load a url , the html tag "select" does not work to call ajax and return data to other
"select".
the url is "http://www.pcschool.com.tw/query/tCourse.aspx".
But this html can work in the chrome browser.
what's wrong?

here is my webview settings:

```
private void setWebView() {

WebChromeClient wcc = new WebChromeClient() {

};

web.setWebChromeClient(wcc);

WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

web.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface() , "android_interface");

WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,String url) {

        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    System.out.println("------------shouldOverrideUrlLoading------------");
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                   super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                  web.loadUrl("javascript:window.android_interface.
                   checkLoginSession(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");

    }


    };

       web.setWebViewClient(wvc);

       //web.loadUrl("http://www.pcschool.com.tw/query/tCourse.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Try adding a WebChromeClient, with this client you can 'debug' your Javascript.

Comment: If you are using KitKat you can also use these tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Comment: The javascript is work. it just can't work in webview in "some" phones.